# getJSON not working. got tired of js problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

```
function addSearchPattern(file, aStatus, aRule, aExpression, aCategory)
{
    $.getJSON(file, {
        status: aStatus,
        rule: aRule,
        expression: aExpression,
        categoryID: aCategory
    }, function(data){
        if(data.errors.length > 0)
        {
            var errorText = '';
            $.each(data.errors, function(i, errors){
                errorText += data.errors[i];
            })
            alert(errorText);
        }
    });
}
```

this method should work but for some unknown reason it doesn't work. Even if i remove the callback steps of the function(data) still won't work. I tried to access the php file using the URL with GET parameters and it works perfectly fine. It even returns the JSON object. WHAT AM I MISSING HERE?

Comment: any errors ? are you trying to load from another domain ? (that is not allowed) .. Tell us how you invoke it and what the erros are..

Comment: same host, it's just that i've written everything in a js file and made some methods to accept parameters. I tried even writing it in the same html file. No luck. In firebug console there is no error just that data.errors is null which i don't understand why since the array is perfectly encoded.

Comment: What is the value of `data`? Or, can you provide us a copy with the JSON that comes back?

Answer (score 2):

Implement an [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler to help see why it fails..

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to debug it in Firebug? Watch the Net tab after the AJAX request finished to verify that the request return an intended response. Check if the HTML page is valid, no missing close tag, and no javascript error in the page.